# Why regex routes in Zend Framework is not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

Few months ago, I was worked on website using ZF3 and site was working properly. Now I am configuring this site on different server and getting 404 error for some urls.

configuration code is:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'announcements' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/announcements[/:id][/:action]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'id' => '[0-9]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],                
        ],   
    ],      
],
```

http://example.com/announcements    => **Working**

http://example.com/announcements/2  => **Working**

http://example.com/announcements/send  => **Not Working**

So could someone suggest me how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: What's the version of `zend-router` ? Because I tried the same exact configuration with version `3.3.0` and it is working. Therefore, there are two options: you're using an older (and bugged) version, or your server configuration (vhost/htaccess) is different from the previous (and working) one.

Comment: I think you are right. May be server configuration is different

Comment: PHP version is the same between the two servers?

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` in the URL is completely optional, then I would suggest actually having three routes:

```
'route'    => '/announcements[/:id][/:action]'
'route'    => '/announcements[/:id]'
'route'    => '/announcements[/:action]'
```

They are really three separate endpoints, because `id` and `action` might occur together, separately, or not at all.

Comment: Is this possible to define one regex for these urls? because before these urls were working fine with one regex.

Comment: The logical problem with `[0-9]*`, as I see it, is that you are suggesting that an incoming path could be completely empty, but I'm not sure this would work.  If you want `[0-9]+`, then leave as is, otherwise, define a path where the `id` is not a path component at all.

Comment: Would suggest that in your first route the `/:id` is _not_ optional, as you've also provided an optional route